# collectStyles not getting styles from Root App Component in styled-components SSR

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components for my react app. When we are adding styled-components in client-side it is working fine but during SSR, ServerStyleSheet.collectStyles is unable to get the styles from the root app component. When I use GlobalStyle with the root app component collectStyles is getting styles for Global Styles but not from the root app component.

with the below code I am unable to get any styles.

```
html = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(
        <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context} history={history}>
              <React.Fragment>
                <App />
              </React.Fragment>
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider >
        </Loadable.Capture>
      ));
```

with this code I am able to get styles for GlobalStyle but not for root App component.

```
html = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(
        <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context} history={history}>
              <React.Fragment>
                <App />
                <GlobalStyle/>
              </React.Fragment>
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider >
        </Loadable.Capture>
      ));
```